# Performing a contains select statement in SQL

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a column which contains some strings. What I need is get user input and perform a sql select statement on those rows which contains the text the user entered . Taking an example lets say I have a column called "drinks". One of the rows has something like "Tea"+"Coffee" inside the drinks column. Now if the user enters either tea or coffee I need that row to be returned. What is the best way to perform this operation?

```
 id   ingredients  drinks
  1   milk,sugar    tea+coffee
```

Comment: can you give sample records first in tabular format?

Comment: Added one sample record

Comment: Your DB is not normalized.

Comment: why are you storing comma separated value in the table? bad design. you should normalize your table properly.

Comment: That is part of the issue here since the process which involves updating the table data is kind of automated and hard to change. It gets data from several places on the web. This data is stored in a particular form and is kind of difficult for me to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to search a term at time, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE
  FIND_IN_SET('tea', REPLACE(drinks, '+', ','))
```

or if you know already the number of drinks to search you could add some OR conditions:

```
WHERE
  FIND_IN_SET('tea', REPLACE(drinks, '+', ',')) OR
  FIND_IN_SET('coffee', REPLACE(drinks, '+', ','))
```

Comment: add another find_in_set that checks for coffee.

Comment: @JW웃 i'm not sure if the OP wants to search only one term at time or more than one... but i edited my answer! tnx!